# C# Web Api 2 PUT and POST requests "not supported"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-ajax

So far I have my ASP.NET web api correctly doing a get request for an employee and filling in the fields from that using JQuery. The delete request works also but I keep receiving:

```
Message=The requested resource does not support http method 'PUT'.
```

with a 405 http method not allowed error. This may be because my put/post requests include both an object,string as parameters instead of simply getting the id of the url to GET and DELETE. This is a cross-origin request from one site to another so I have enableCors() in my web.config file as well as the removing of WEBDAV:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
  <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
  <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <clear />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://chad-dev.clas.uconn.edu" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="WebDAV" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers></system.webServer>
```

Here is my WebApiConfig Register function:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        //config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
        config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "WithAction",
            "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Commitments", action = "GetCommitment" }
        );
```

My controller:

```
[HttpPut]
    public IHttpActionResult PutEmployee([FromBody]EmployeeModel employeeModel, string netId)
    {     
        var chadResult = new CLASWebApiResponse
        {
            Success = true,
            ResponseMessage = "Success",
            Data = null
        };
        try
        {
            employee employeeUpdate = masterDb.employees.Find(employeeModel.Id);

            if (employeeUpdate == null)
            {
                chadResult.ResponseMessage = "Employee not found";
                chadResult.Success = false;
                return Ok(chadResult);
            }

            employeeUpdate.netid = employeeModel.NetId;
            employeeUpdate.enumber = employeeModel.Enumber;
            employeeUpdate.peoplesoft = employeeModel.Peoplesoft;
            employeeUpdate.email = employeeModel.Email;
            employeeUpdate.tenure_year = employeeModel.TenureYear;
            employeeUpdate.tenure_indicator = employeeModel.TenureIndicator;
            employeeUpdate.hire_date = employeeModel.HireDate;
            employeeUpdate.gender = employeeModel.Gender;
            employeeUpdate.birth_date = employeeModel.BirthDate;
            employeeUpdate.updated_by = netId;
            masterDb.SaveChanges();

            chadResult.Success = true;
            chadResult.ResponseMessage = "Success";
            return Ok(chadResult);
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            chadResult.ResponseMessage = e.Message;
            chadResult.Success = false;
            return Ok(chadResult);
        }
    }
```

And finally (sorry for the amount of code), my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "PUT",
            url: "https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Employees/PutEmployee",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({employeeModel:employeeData, netId:'22'}),
            traditional: true,
            success: function() {
                console.log(employeeModel);
                alert("Saved Successfully.");
            },
            error: function(response) {
                console.log(employeeModel);
                alert("Employee data failed to save to server. Error message: " + jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Why isn't your controller method just called Put? Also, based on your routing configuration, you should rename the `netId` parameter to `id` and then put the value in the URL instead of in the request body.

Comment: I am not only passing the netId string but also an entire employee object. Can that fit all in the URL? I thought that would go in the JSON request body

Comment: Why even pass a netId if the employeeModel already has one?

Comment: the netId passed for PUT and POST is the person making the put changes. It is used for the created_by/updated_by field in our database.

Comment: If you're using WebAPI you should be using proper REST syntax: `https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Employees/123` where 123 should be the ID of the resource you're updating (i.e., the employee record). Then your `EmployeeModel` is in the request body. If you really want, you can add `netId` to the query string. This will match your DefaultApi route configuration.

Comment: Just add a updated_by field to your employee model. Then in javascript do  employeeData. updated_by = 22 and remove the need for the netId field.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) Web api will try to get the string value from the URL and you are providing it on the request body.

Try to change your ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "https://chad-test4.clas.uconn.edu/api/Employees/PutEmployee?netId=22",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({employeeModel:employeeData}),
        traditional: true,
        success: function() {
            console.log(employeeModel);
            alert("Saved Successfully.");
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(employeeModel);
            alert("Employee data failed to save to server. Error message: " + jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText).Message);
        }
    });
```

You wouldn't need to annotate EmployeeModel with [FromBody], as it is a complex object.
Web Api default serialization will try to get it from the body by default.

NOTE: If netID is the ID of the user updating the resouce it is better to have a property UpdatedBy in EmployeeModel.
Following REST principles, PUT requests should have the ID of the *resource* in the URL