# No candidates found for the request even though the route exists

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a Controller which has the following declaration

```
[Authorize(Roles = Role.Admin)]
[ApiController]
[Route("meta/[controller]")]
public class ActionParameterController : BaseController<ActionParameterController>
```

Inside it there is the following method

```
[HttpPost("insert/{action}/{entity}")]
public IActionResult InsertActionParameter(
    [FromBody] MetaActionParameter parameter,
    int action,
    int entity)
```

However when I try to do the POST request to this endpoint I get 404.
The url:

```
http://localhost:5000/meta/actionParameter/insert/2/2
```

Console output is:

```
2021-08-19 14:03:35.311 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics.POST) [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.14.104:5000/meta/actionParameter/insert/1/2 - 0
2021-08-19 14:03:38.116 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware.) [Verbose] All hosts are allowed.
2021-08-19 14:03:38.117 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.POST) [Debug] "POST" requests are not supported
2021-08-19 14:03:38.120 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.POST) [Debug] "POST" requests are not supported
2021-08-19 14:03:38.125 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.POST) [Debug] "POST" requests are not supported
2021-08-19 14:03:38.132 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.) [Debug] AuthenticationScheme: "Bearer" was not authenticated.
2021-08-19 14:03:38.180 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.) [Debug] No candidates found for the request path '"/meta/actionParameter/insert/1/2"'
2021-08-19 14:03:38.182 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.) [Debug] Request did not match any endpoints
2021-08-19 14:03:38.185 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.) [Debug] Connection id ""0HMB303OBKKOL"" completed keep alive response.
2021-08-19 14:03:38.191 (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics.POST) [Information] Request finished HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.14.104:5000/meta/actionParameter/insert/1/2 - 0 - 404 0 - 2880.056
```

I tried getting all routes from `IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider` and the route is printed. There are other routes in that controller that do work.

If I change the route to be only "insert" the request goes through. From what I can see, there is no conflict between routes.

What further steps should I take to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Had similar log message but finally found out that the Action somehow had changed from public to private....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

I think the action and/or insert words are probably reserved words.

I tested with the following code and it worked:

```cs
    [HttpGet("insert/{xaction}/{xentity}")]
    public IActionResult InsertActionParameterGet(int xaction, int xentity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(xaction + " " + xentity);
    
        return new JsonResult("Ok");
}
```

Notice I just added an "x" to action and entity, just as a test.
Also, I did a test on a GET action.
Before adding the "x", it was not working, so I do think those are reserved words probably.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the complete router at Http Method Attribute, like this:

```
[HttpPost("meta/ActionParameter/insert/{action}/{entity}")]
public IActionResult InsertActionParameter([FromBody] MetaActionParameter parameter, int action, int entity)
```

Comment: If I set the whole route, the actual generated route becomes `meta/ActionParameter/meta/ActionParameter/insert/{action}/{entity}`, because the controller has `[Route("meta/[controller]")]`

Comment: Do you compile and test, or is it a conjecture?

Comment: Yes, I tested it just to be sure. It still does not work. Other routes work on this controller, just this one is being rebellious.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question here: [C# Web Api 2 PUT and POST requests "not supported"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439939/c-sharp-web-api-2-put-and-post-requests-not-supported)

Based on that one, it looks like you should not be using **[FromBody]**.
So your method signature should look something like this:

```cs
   [HttpPost("insert/{action}/{entity}")]
   public IActionResult InsertActionParameter(int action, int entity)
```

To ready the body of the request, you could do something like this:

```cs
            var bodyStr = "";
            var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
    
            // Allows using several time the stream in ASP.Net Core
            req.EnableRewind(); 
    
            // Arguments: Stream, Encoding, detect encoding, buffer size 
            // AND, the most important: keep stream opened
            using (StreamReader reader 
                      = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8, true, 1024, true))
            {
                bodyStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
    
            // Rewind, so the core is not lost when it looks the body for the request
            req.Body.Position = 0;
    
            // Do whatever work with bodyStr here
```

Comment: I change the signature according to your answer, but the error still persists.

Comment: Can you share your source code or link to git repo, might be able to help more that way.